# When using UIScrollView, how do I make the viewed ends to be complete, not partial

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

How do I make the UIScroll view show complete views, not partial views?
(Note)  I don't want it jumping to a complete view.  It needs to move naturally or at least not immediate... needs to be smooth.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your views are all of a constant size and you just want left/right or up/down scrolling, set `pagingEnabled` on the scroll view to `YES`. Supposing you wanted your scroll view to be 320x480 but to show the sides of the next and previous pages (so, e.g., each thing inside the view was 280 points wide), you'd size the scroll view to be 280x480 but set `masksToBounds` to `NO`.

If you have a more complicated scheme, install a scroll view delegate and act on `scrollViewDidScroll:`, paying attention to `contentOffset`. Probably you want to implement logic like:

- add an observer on `tracking`; when it transitions to `NO` from 'YES' enable your logic inside `scrollViewDidScroll:` In there:

  - if a forced scroll is pending, cancel it
  - calculate where you'd force the scrolling to from the current position
  - schedule a scroll to there (which you'll effect via `setContentOffset:animated:`) for half a second from now

You can use a non-repeating `NSTimer` for the scheduling aspect. The logic you've essentially implemented is that if the user stops adjusting the view, wait for the natural inertia to end (which you'll detect by the 0.5 second gap since last movement), then transition smoothly to the nearest aligned position.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Apple's documentation here first:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/Introduction/Introduction.html

Then the ScrollViewSuite sample:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008904

I think you are referring to Paging techniques.